# Overriding jmeter.properties

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to re-read jmeter.properties without closing and restarting JMeter?

Maybe any additional class that will trigger this process?

Sometimes I need to play with a property's values, and it is not convenient to restart JMeter every time, so I'd like to automate this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to re-read jmeter properties from file - jmeter has enough built-in functionality to read/set values of properties.
At least the following below:

- jmeter [functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):
  [_*setProperty()*](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty),
  [_property()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property),
  [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P);
- [props - JMeterProperties (class java.util.Properties)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) - to access from beanshell code;
- [Property Display](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Property_Display).

Look also into the following for more info and examples:

- [Using JMeter properties](http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.com/2010/01/tip-4-using-jmeter-properties.html)
- [How to set a javascript value as a JMeter property](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-to-set-a-javascript-value-as-a-JMeter-property-td5577158.html)
- [Jmeter Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#How_do_I_pass_parameters_into_my_Test_scripts.3F_I_want_to_be_able_to_use_the_same_script_to_test_with_different_numbers_of_threads_and_loops.2C_and_I_don.27t_want_to_have_to_change_the_script_each_time)