# jmeter GUI setting https.use.cached.ssl.context=false

Tags: java, jmeter

I am new to jmeter so I'm not sure how to do this. In the jmeter [docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

I want to set this in my JMX file

`https.use.cached.ssl.context=false`

How can I do this in the jmeter GUI?

Comment: basically what you want is to modify jmeter.properties at runtime, which is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427949/overriding-jmeter-properties

Comment: do you want to set it for every request in that jmx, or do you want to use that as your default value? Or do you want to use that or some requests only? Each of those (could be) a different answer. @KirilS.'s link is for the latter.

Comment: @RowlandB if it could be in a JMX for every request that would be very useful!

Comment: @RowlandB I got a bit of help from someone and they mentioned that this value should be set in the `jmeter.properties` file within `/jmeter/bin`. In my use case, I am uploading this JMX file to `Redline13` which will help me distribute this JMX file to X number of EC2 instances and run the test for me. Would I be able to have this property in my JMX file and ultimately run this across all EC2 instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this property set in all of your scripts, change the commented-out `#https.use.cached.ssl.context=true` in `jmeter.properties` to `https.use.cached.ssl.context=false`.

If you want this only for `my_test.jmx`, then copy `jmeter.properties` to `my_test.properties` and make the change there. When you start jmeter from the command line, you can specify that file with `-p`.

Alternatively, you can specify just that property with `-J`. See [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) for Jmeter command line options.

As for `Redline13`, it [looks like](https://www.redline13.com/blog/jmeter-command-line-options/) they use `-J`, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: RedLine13 allows both passing properties via -J and technically passing in custom properties file and using -p